# sql server 2008 multiple inserts over 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, insert

I got the following trigger on my sql server 2008 database

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_stoelen
ON Passenger
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(
                SELECT 1
                FROM Passenger p 
                INNER JOIN Inserted i on i.flight= p.flight
                WHERE p.flight= i.flightAND p.seat= i.seat
             )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Seat taken!',16,1)
            ROLLBACK TRAN   
        END
END
```

The trigger is throwing errors when i try to run the query below. This query i supposed to insert two different passengers in a database on two different flights. I'm sure both seats aren't taken, but i can't figure out why the trigger is giving me the error. Does it have to do something with correlation?

```
INSERT INTO passagier VALUES 
(13392,5315,3,'Janssen Z','2A','October 30, 2006 10:43','M'),
(13333,5316,2,'Janssen Q','2A','October 30, 2006 11:51','V')
```

UPDATE: 
The table looks as below

```
CREATE TABLE Passagier
(
    passengernumber int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_passagier PRIMARY KEY(passagiernummer),
    flight int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_passagier_vlucht REFERENCES vlucht(vluchtnummer) 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    desk int NULL CONSTRAINT FK_passagier_balie REFERENCES balie(balienummer) 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    seat char(3) NULL,
    checkInTime datetime NULL,
    gender char(1) NULL
)
```

Comment: What is the table schema please?

Comment: sorry for the mix of dutch and english. But i'm working in holland, only translating for better understanding here ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems with this subquery:

```
SELECT 1
FROM Passenger p 
INNER JOIN Inserted i on i.flight= p.flight
WHERE p.flight= i.flight AND p.seat= i.seat
```

First of all, the `WHERE p.flight = i.flight` is quite unnecessary, as it's already part of your join.

Second, the `p.seat = i.seat` should also be part of the `JOIN`.

Third, this trigger runs **after** the rows have been inserted, so this will *always* match, and your trigger will therefore *always* raise an error and roll back.

You can fix the trigger, but a much better method would be to not use a trigger at all.  If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, all you need is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `flight, seat`:

```
ALTER TABLE passgier
ADD CONSTRAINT IX_passagier_flightseat
UNIQUE (flight, seat)
```

Comment: What i'm trying to do is insert two (or more) passengers with one insert statement. The passengers in the example are on different flights.

i'll try your suggestion with an index. Good one, never thought of it!

Comment: @Aaronaught thanks for the quick and good response! It seems to be solved with the index! Thanks for the great tip.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your trigger after inserting a record, and then look for a record with the values you just inserted, you will always find it. You might try an INSTEAD OF trigger so you can check for an existing records before actually doing the insert.

Comment: an intead of trigger doesn't seem to be working. I just tried it and management studio says '2 rows affected' but nothing happens

Comment: Did you INSERT again within the trigger? With an INSTEAD OF trigger you have to do the actual insert within the trigger (if the data passes your test). Anyway, I see that Aaronaught's good idea worked for you, so that is good news.

Answer (score 0):

It might be throwing the error by finding itself in the table (circular reference back to itself).  You might want to add an additional filter to the where clause like " AND Passenger.ID <> inserted.ID "